# Convert png image to gif without losing transparency

Tags: image

Hi,

I have a transparent png format image.But SAP system does not support PNG format.So I want to convert it to either GIF or JPEG. I tried to convert it using Adobe Photoshop and some other tools but the resulted image loses its transparency. Can any body please tell me solution ??? [Here is my image](http://postimage.org/image/54fh8g2a9/)

Comment: This does not seem to be programming related.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can convert png to either GIF or JPEG without losing transparency.......
this is done though the help of php lang...

```
<?php
$src = imagecreatefrompng("original_image.png");
$newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
 imagealphablending($newImg, false);
 imagesavealpha($newImg,true);
 $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
 imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
 imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight,
                      $imgInfo[0], $imgInfo[1]);

imagejpeg($newImg,"jpec_test_1.JPG",100);


imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($newImg);

?>
```

Comment: The image is semi-transparent, which is not supported by the GIF file format. Even a script cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert to JPEG as it does not support transparency. You should be able to conver to a GIF, just make sure to check the box next to transparency. However, the image you linked to actually does not appear to have transparency. Luckily, the image is a very simple gradient and you can easily reproduce this in Photoshop and then save it out as a GIF w/ transparency.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I am not good at Photoshop.So that I just tried to convert the existed image to gif.I put the checkbox but no result.Actually I want to use it for my Color Picker application   http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ ...The middle overlay image of that application is transparent... If you dont mind,Can you convert that image to gif... I am really thankful to you...

Answer (score 0):

Even if I didn't quickly succeed to accomplish that with the Gimp, I've found a site which suits your needs. It is a online tool: you haven't to download anything, just upload your png image and then download the generated gif. Try it:

> http://images.my-addr.com/converter_png_to_gif_online_freeware_tool.php

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried there already but It converts without transparency which cannot perform colorpicker applicaion....

Comment: @RamaRaoM: It seems to preserve the alpha-channel. I opened the converted file with Gimp, and there's still the alpha-channel, as well. Are you sure?

Comment: @RamaRaoM: The alpha channel is widely used in the png format mostly, it could defined by `a portion of each pixel's data that is reserved for transparency information`. The alpha channel is really a  `mask` -- it specifies how the pixel's colors should be merged with another pixel when the two are overlaid, one on top of the other (from http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/alpha_channel.html).

Comment: K..then can we convert that image to gif by preserving alpha-channel?

Comment: Well, in gif format the above isn't literally called alpha channel, actually. But the transparency can work even so. I suppose Gimp calls it alpha channel, both for png and for gif images. But the technology behind differs, as you can read in http://images.my-addr.com/converter_png_to_gif_online_freeware_tool.php, on top.

Comment: Have you tried with OP's image? It removes the transparency and assumes a white background. IMHO GIFs do not support alpha-channel. Transparency is either on or off.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Valjas, you JPEG doesn't support transparency. If you are converting just for reducing file size as JPEG has better compression, you might want to use https://tinypng.com/. It also has an API. I just used it for reducing file size of few PNGs.

BTW, I found this information while I was chasing the same problem ;)